# Iterating through an Object array

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have created an object array with the following code:

```
$data = (object)array();
```

and populated it with data.  it's results should look something like this when i'm done:

```
Data->  accounts->  54->    today-> sales
                    checkout_fees
                    trans_fees
                    payable
                week->  sales
                    checkout_fees
                    trans_fees
                    payable
                month-> sales
                    checkout_fees
                    trans_fees
                    payable
                year->  sales
                    checkout_fees
                    trans_fees
                    payable
            55->    today-> sales
                    checkout_fees
                    trans_fees
                    payable
                week->  sales
                    checkout_fees
                    trans_fees
                    payable
                month-> sales
                    checkout_fees
                    trans_fees
                    payable
                year->  sales
                    checkout_fees
                    trans_fees
                    payable
```

When i try to perform a foreach on an element in the tree it fails:

```
    foreach ($data->accounts as $account) {
        echo ("Working to calculate account for account ".$account."<br>\n");
    }
```

the error i get is this:

Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

I presume this is because I am trying to echo an array instead of the actual "account" name.  Is there a way to grab this account name or it's sub (i.e. 55) and set it to a variable? I will need that same variable to iterate through and perform calculations on data in the array under it so this would help two-fold.

Thanks,

Silver Tiger

---

UPDATE: *************************************************

---

Here is my object:

```
object(stdClass)#11 (4) { 
    ["56"]=> object(stdClass)#12 (3) { 
        ["week"]=> object(stdClass)#13 (4) { 
            ["sales"]=> float(6) 
            ["checkout_fees"]=> float(0) 
            ["trans_fees"]=> float(0.67) } 
        ["month"]=> object(stdClass)#21 (4) { 
            ["sales"]=> float(6) 
            ["checkout_fees"]=> float(0) 
            ["trans_fees"]=> float(0.67) } 
        ["year"]=> object(stdClass)#27 (4) { 
            ["sales"]=> float(6) 
            ["checkout_fees"]=> float(0) 
            ["trans_fees"]=> float(0.67) } } 
    ["55"]=> object(stdClass)#15 (3) { 
        ["week"]=> object(stdClass)#16 (4) { 
            ["sales"]=> float(24) 
            ["checkout_fees"]=> float(0) 
            ["trans_fees"]=> float(0.67) } 
        ["month"]=> object(stdClass)#23 (5) { 
            ["sales"]=> float(24) 
            ["checkout_fees"]=> float(0) 
            ["trans_fees"]=> float(0.67) 
            ["payable"]=> string(5) "14.00" } 
        ["year"]=> object(stdClass)#29 (5) { 
            ["sales"]=> float(24) 
            ["checkout_fees"]=> float(0) 
            ["trans_fees"]=> float(2.68) 
            ["payable"]=> string(5) "14.00" } } 
    ["54"]=> object(stdClass)#18 (3) { 
        ["week"]=> object(stdClass)#19 (4) { 
            ["sales"]=> float(4) 
            ["checkout_fees"]=> float(0) 
            ["trans_fees"]=> float(0.67) } 
        ["month"]=> object(stdClass)#25 (4) { 
            ["sales"]=> float(4) 
            ["checkout_fees"]=> float(0) 
            ["trans_fees"]=> float(0.67) } 
        ["year"]=> object(stdClass)#31 (4) { 
            ["sales"]=> float(4) 
            ["checkout_fees"]=> float(0) 
            ["trans_fees"]=> float(0.67) } } 
    ["45"]=> object(stdClass)#33 (3) { 
        ["week"]=> object(stdClass)#34 (1) { 
            ["payable"]=> string(5) "15.00" } 
        ["month"]=> object(stdClass)#35 (1) { 
            ["payable"]=> string(5) "15.00" } 
        ["year"]=> object(stdClass)#36 (1) { 
            ["payable"]=> string(5) "15.00" 
            } 
        } 
    }
 }
```

I understand it has a heirarchy as it should like a multidimensional array might, but each item is an object.  I would need to either be able to grab the name of an object and use that and reference data using the $data->accounts-$variable->week->sales.

I will also look into converting an object into an array to work with it, I was just looking for the best solution.

---

### UPDATE:

```
for ($counter=1; $counter < 9999; $counter++) {
    if (isset($data->{$counter})) {
        echo "Account number ".$counter." has data.<br>\n";
    }
}
```

Effectively the loop above gives me all the "accounts" that need. I could shove these into an array to use for iteration through my objects and complete the calculations I need, though this is a terribly inefficient way to get a list I have found no way to reference an object's name other than to directly reference it specifically and unfortunately my list is created dynamically .. there's no way to tell in advance.

does anyone know a better method to get the list of accounts ID's at the 2nd level of the object?

Thanks,

Silver Tiger

---

### UPDATE:

I ended up just querying my database to see which accounts were active on both the "sales" side adn "payable" side and it returned the same list of accounts (45, 54, 55, 56) that was present when creating the object int he first place. I am now using this result to process the data as needed.

Thank you though.

Comment: Basic syntax of classes is here - http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: There's no such thing as an "object array". You have an **object**, period. Are all properties of the object objects as well? What does `var_dump` give you?

Comment: `var_dump` your object. then you will understand why it says "***Object*** of class ***stdClass***" cannot be converted.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php

Answer (score 1):

Your `$account` variable is an object itself, for example:

```
54->        today-> sales
                checkout_fees
                trans_fees
                payable
            week->  sales
                checkout_fees
                trans_fees
                payable
            month-> sales
                checkout_fees
                trans_fees
                payable
            year->  sales
                checkout_fees
                trans_fees
                payable
```

This cannot be converted to a string.

Use this instead:

```
foreach ($data->accounts as $account) {
    echo ("Working to calculate account for account:");
    var_dump($account);
}
```

---

You might also be interested in converting your stdClass object into an array. I'd refer you to this:

http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2009/php-tip-convert-stdclass-object-to-multidimensional-array-and-convert-multidimensional-array-to-stdclass-object/

Answer (score -1):

You have got a composed object, so you need to iterate through each level of your composition to display the strings *inside* the composite (if that is what you try to achieve, it was not entirely clear to me what you question aims for):

```
Data ->
  accounts ->
    account (numbered) ->
      period ->
        fees
```

In PHP:

```
foreach($data->accounts as $account)
   foreach($account as $period)
       foreach($period as $fee)
           echo $fee, "\n";
```

---

If I read your comment right you need to access the numbered properties, you can do so by putting them into curly brackets:

```
$data->accounts->{54}->week->sales - $data->accounts->{55}->week->transaction_fees
```

---

As you then wrote in your comment that you've got a problem to find about all numbers of accounts, which are just object variables of `$data->accounts`. You can get such a list by using the [`get_object_vars`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) function:

```
$numbers = get_object_vars($data->accounts);
```

I hope this helps you to continue further.

Comment: my goal was to get a list of the numberred account ID's (i.e. 54, 55, 56) iterate through that set of values using each as $account, so i could do something like this: $weeknetsales = ($data->accounts->$account->week->sales - $data->accounts->$account->week->transaction_fees)

Comment: ah .. unfortunately I don't know ahead of time the what the 'numbers' will be as this is populated with PHP.  I was trying to do a foreach so it would automatically grab them and work with them until there were no more .. so my alternative is to acquire a list of them and do something with that list.

Comment: @Silvertiger: I added another code-example which should give you that list.

Comment: Thank you , i was on vacation for a bit, but I will see if I can implement that change as it may save a DB query and time.  Thank you.